# self-triggered always block using delay

Tags: verilog

I need to implement a block (behavioral, not to be synthesized) which is either triggered by

a) an external event eflag, or, b) depending on its state, an internal event iflag, scheduled dt seconds later, whichever comes first.

My trials using the delay (#) operator resulted in a blocking behavior, e.g. a long dt did block the next eflag.
If possible, I would avoid dtmax as counting overhead for long dt.

Working and intended, but failing code:

```
`timescale 1ns/100fs
`define tick 1.0e-9 

parameter real  dtmax = 1;

initial iflag=1'b0;
initial toggle=1'b0;

always @(eflag, iflag) begin    
    // time step control

    dt = ...;
    iticks = dt/`tick;
    toggle = !toggle;
end

//------------------------------------------------------
/*
a) time step counter - working
always #1 begin
    iticks = iticks - 1;
    if (iticks < 1) begin 
        iflag = !iflag;  
        iticks=dtmax/`tick;
    end
end
*/

// b) intended
always @(toggle) begin
    #(iticks) iflag <= !iflag;          // failing, not changing iflag
 // #(iticks) iflag = !iflag;           // failing, blocking simulation
end
```

You can try it on edaplayground
[link](https://www.edaplayground.com/x/2pVV)

Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have chanaged your code and this new code works fine for me. If you think it is not working, maybe you are wrong in understanding Verilog simulation. Non-blocking delays schedule an event on a signal. If before the time of assigning that scheduling,  another event is scheduled, with a different value, it overrides the first one. If new event has the same value,  the first one is kept.

```
// Verilog
// self-triggered always block
// block should take time steps <= dtmax


`define tick 1.0e-9

module dut(eflag);

  input eflag;
reg   iflag;
reg   toggle;
  integer iticks;
  real    last_time;
  real    now;
  real    dtlast;
  real    dtmax;

  always @(eflag, iflag) begin  

    now    = $time*`tick;
    dtlast = now - last_time;
    dtmax  = iticks*`tick; // from last call

    $display(  "dtlast:  %g",dtlast);
    $display(  "err:     %d",dtlast > dtmax); // giving wrong value in sim?
    $display("\nnow:     %g",now);
    $display(  "dtmax:   %g",dtmax);


    // time step control dummy
    iticks <= 7 + $random % 5; //changed because in previous one eflag and toggle always changed at the same time
    toggle = !toggle;

    last_time = now;
  end

  initial toggle = 0;
  initial iflag = 0;
  always @(toggle) begin
    #(iticks) iflag <= !iflag; 
  end

endmodule
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, actually I wanted to get rid of the pedestrian style of decrementing. Please see my edited code in the question.

Comment: what if you change it to   iflag <=#(iticks) !iflag;

Comment: Can modify your question to be more clear and post your whole code, so that I can debug it.

Comment: Hi Laleh, 
thanks for taking this. I have put it on edaplayground
[link](https://www.edaplayground.com/x/2pVV)
and will edit the question later.

Comment: @bardo See the answer.

Comment: > toggle and eflag always changed at the same time

Correct! - Thanks a lot for pointing this out.

Comment: Your welcome. Also notice that iflag and toggle do not need to be integers. Their value is either 0 or 1. So declare them as reg. Also input must always be wire. Not reg, Not integer (in synthesizable code ).